# Using MagicalRecord's saveInBackgroundWithBlock: with findAll

Tags: objective-c, core-data, magicalrecord

Since the documentation is a little spotty, I was wondering if anyone can shed some light on how/when exactly to use saveInBackgroundWithBlock.

I have a batch process I run in the background after every launch to update some values in Core Data. However, when I run this bit of code (simplified):

```
[MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *context) {
        NSArray *all = [Event findAll];
        for (Event *event in all) {
            event.timestamp = [NSDate date];
        }
 }];
```

The context never has any changes when it comes time to save it. However, when I do something like:

```
[MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *context) {
        NSArray *all = [Event findAll];
        for (Event *event in all) {
            Event *tmpEvent = [event inContext:context];
            tmpEvent.timeStamp = [NSDate date];
        }
}];
```

Everything is fine and the changes show up. The only issue I see is if I use findAll, all the event's data is faulted:

```
(lldb) po event
(Event *) $1 = 0x07497c90 <Event: 0x7497c90> (entity: Event; id: 0x7490a50 <x-coredata://2DB960AE-FA52-42A7-9A5F-957199076FF7/Event/p1> ; data: <fault>)
(lldb) po tmpEvent
(Event *) $2 = 0x08574250 <Event: 0x8574250> (entity: Event; id: 0x7490a50 <x-coredata://2DB960AE-FA52-42A7-9A5F-957199076FF7/Event/p1> ; data: {
    name = Test;
    number = 0;
    timeStamp = "2012-10-15 16:18:39 +0000";
})
```

If I'm using saveInBackground incorrectly, I can always just use NSOperationQueue block operation in conjunction with MagicalRecord's context threading but I was hoping to be able to use this bit of syntactical sugar to make my code a little cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use it more like this:

```
[MagicalRecord saveInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSManagedObjectContext *localContext){
    NSArray *all = [Event findAllInContext:localContext];
    for (Event *event in all)
    {
        event.timeStamp = [NSDate date];
    }

}];
```

Use the local context for **EVERYTHING** when you use the background block. The background block is doing all the setup required for you to do stuff off the main thread/queue. As such, you should do all your background operations in a context that isn't the "main" context, as set up for you by MagicalRecord.

Comment: Ah, can't believe I didn't try that. I thought 'findAll' using 'MR_contextForCurrentThread' would take care of that but looking closer, localContext is created separately from the thread contexts.